# What is the meaning of "physical character of of the people"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, writing, nineteenth-century-english

[Sir John Barrow, 1st Baronet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_John_Barrow,_1st_Baronet) published the book "[Travels in China](https://artsandculture.google.com/asset/travels-in-china-barrow-john-sir-1764-1848/6QHg5u9ByuoKIw?hl=en)" in 1804. In Chapter VII. **Government—Laws** he said

> It is sufficiently evident, that the heavy hand of power has
> completely overcome and moulded to its own shape the **physical
> character of the people**, and that their moral sentiments and actions
> are swayed by the opinions, and almost under the entire dominion, of
> the government.

What is the meaning of **physical character**? The dictionary normally says **physical** means "relating to the body as opposed to the mind". But in that sentence "physical character" seems to relate to mind not human body. So I think it may just mean **moral character** because in Chapter IV **Moral Character of the People** he said

> I have already had occasion to observe that the natural disposition of
> the Chinese should seem to have suffered almost a total change by the
> influence of the laws and maxims of government, an influence which, in
> this country more than elsewhere, has given a bias to the manners,
> sentiments, and **moral character of the people**.

But in this book he used these two words together several time, e.g."Comparison of the **Physical and Moral Characters** of the Chinese and Mantchoo Tartars."

And in a note he wrote,

> Had not Lord Kames written upon a system of a separate and local
> creation, pre-established in his own mind, he would unquestionably
> have laid more stress upon a resemblance in **their physical characters**,
> in their superstitions and religious notions ...

So he seemed not to equal *physical characters to moral characters*

BTW, this question is a spinoff from my question “[How many times in history did the government completely "moulded to its own shape the physical character of the people"?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/68847/how-many-times-in-history-did-the-government-completely-moulded-to-its-own-shap)” I asked at history SE

Comment: Have you looked up [physical](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/physical) (sense 3) and [character](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/character) (sense 3)?

Comment: Yes I looked physical up as in " relating to the body as opposed to the mind" hence the question. I should add this to my question.

Comment: Well, that is the answer. He is talking about the bodily characteristics of the people.

Comment: I'd say it's a strange usage here. I'd guess it's equivalent to _gross_ in [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gross)'s (archaic) sense 1c (immediately obvious) (grading to overridingly prevalent). But this is an opinion, so I'll not post as an 'answer'. But changing the shape of people sounds like making Uruk-hai.

Comment: @ColinFine "bodily characteristics" ? Although I can guess that meaning but ...

Comment: It is possible he is referring to the behavioral aspects of the people. Behaviour is the physical manifestation of "moral character" or mentality. An an observation that the peoples character had been moulded would include their day to day behavioural practices.

Comment: @JuanNo because I read the book so I will say your words make a lot sense!

Comment: Hi I provided an answer after some further research. I would like to hear your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The chapter II "Occurrences and Observations in the Navigation of the Yellow
Sea, and the Passage up the Pei-ho, or White River." may provide an answer

> Without, however, making any enquiry into the probability that an
> ancient intercourse might have subsisted between China and the East
> coast of Africa, either by convention for commercial purposes, or that
> Chinese sailors might have been thrown on that coast either in
> Phoenicia, or Arabian, or their own vessels, I happened to observe in
> a former publication of "Travels in Southern Africa,"
>
> as a matter of fact, "that the upper lid of the eye of a real Hottentot, as in that
> of a Chinese, was rounded into the lower on the side next the nose,
> and that it formed not an angle as in the eye of an European—that from
> this circumstance they were known in the colony of the Cape by the
> name of Chinese Hottentots." Further observations have confirmed me in
> the very striking degree of resemblance between them. **Their physical
> characters agree in almost every point**.

> The form of their persons in
> the remarkable smallness of the joints and the extremities, their
> voices and manner of speaking, their temper, their colour and
> features, and particularly that singular shaped eye rounded in the
> corner next the nose like the end of an ellipsis, probably of Tartar
> or Scythian origin, are nearly alike. They also agree in the broad
> root of the nose; or great distance between the eyes...

So he talked about the body resemblance but he also talked "their voices and manner of speaking, their temper".

So I feel Barrow seemed to mixed the physical and moral characters sometimes. But I still feel he meant **moral character** in the sentence "the heavy hand of power has completely overcome and moulded to its own shape the **physical character** of the people".

The latest book about that part of history, as far as I know is "[The Image of China in Western Social and Political Thought](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0333912950)". I saw these words,

> **Moral authoritarianism** from this perspective, had undermined China. Indeed, the Chinese had ‘suffered almost a total change by the
> laws and maxims of government' (Barrow: 160).The ‘heavy hand of power
> had completely overcome and moulded to its own shape the **physical
> character** of the people'(359). Consequently,‘while they are by
> nature quiet, passive and timid the state of society and the abuse of
> the laws by which they are governed, have rendered, them indifferent,
> unfeeling and even cruel'(160). C**entral to this moral and
> civilizational decline** was ...

So the author David Matin Jones also mixed **physical and moral characters** there.

[image: The Image of China in Western Social and Political Thought]